# AngularJS, resolve and unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

I've two routes with resolve. Goes like this:

```
.when('/foos', {
templateUrl: 'views/foos.html',
controller: 'FoosCtrl',
resolve: {
    foo_list: ['$q', '$route', '$timeout', '$location', 'Foos', function($q, $route, $timeout, $location, Foos) {
        // postpone the execution
        var deferred_foo = $q.defer()

        Foos.getFoos({token:session_uid}, successCb)

        function successCb(list) {
            if(list['status'] === 200) {
                deferred_foo.resolve(list)
            }
            else {
                alert('Crashcrashcrash')
                deferred_foo.reject("Something just wasn't right")
                //$location.path('maintenance')
            }
        }
        return deferred_foo.promise
        }]
    }
})
.when('/r/:type/:bar_id', {
    templateUrl: 'views/bar.html',
    controller: 'BarsCtrl',
    resolve: {
        bar: ['$q', '$route', '$timeout', '$location', 'Bars', function($q, $route, $timeout, $location, Bars) {
            // postpone the execution
            var deferred = $q.defer()

            Bars.getBar({type: bar_type}, successCb)    

            function successCb(result) {
                if(result['status'] === 200) {
                    deferred.resolve(result)    
                }
                else {
                    alert('Crashcrashcrash')
                    deferred.reject("Something just wasn't right")
                    $location.path('foos')
                }

                return deferred.promise
                }]
            }
        })
```

Then I've two controllers working like this:

```
 App.controller('FoosCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Foos', 'foo_list', function($scope, $location, Foos, foo_list) {...}

 App.controller('BarsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Bars', 'bar', 'sharedService', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Bars, bar, sharedService) {...}
```

Could somebody explain why Bar works but Foo gives me `Error: Unknown provider: foo_listProvider <- foo_list`? I've tried replacing `foo_list` with different name in case camelCasing did something but didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure Bar works? Probably you don't get any error on Bar because Foo is failing and Bar is not even being created/defined. Have you tried to change the init order?

Comment: Yes. Bar is working perfectly - that's the reason why I'm so frustrated and confused about this. I did Bar section of the app few weeks back and now I wanted to apply resolve to Foo as well.

Comment: If you access `bar` inside the `BarsCtrl` what do you get? Does it contain anything or is just *undefined*?

Comment: ```bar``` passes along the data from getBar properly. Like I said, Bar is not the problem and seems to be working perfectly. Foo also works if I rollback to older version without resolve. It looks like some part gets lost between creating foo_list promise and initiating FooCtrl controller.

Comment: Your successCb in bar function is missing a closing parenthesis, so I wonder how come this doesn't throw SyntaxError on you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still wrestling with this. You're right about the missing parenthesis. However it's not missing in the development code :)

Comment: Are both, Foo and Bar, a provider function? Can you add Foo and Bar to your question so that we get more insights?

Answer (score 181):

So, this question was surprisingly similar to my own which I just figured out with help from the folks over at the Angular IRC channel... are you, by chance, setting up your controller though `ng-controller`? I had:

```
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

... when it should have been removed:

```
    <div>
```

... because I was setting up the controller in the resolve on the router. That's what I was doing and it was causing this very issue. You can see more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18305423/1306982

Comment: So... removing ng-controller= does fix the "unknown provider" error for me... but it also causes the page to go blank and for nothing inside the controller to run (even console.log("hello");). I'm confused - if nothing in the HTML invokes the controller... then the controller is never invoked. What am I missing?

Comment: @shacker asked the question "if nothing in the HTML invokes the controller, then the controller is never invoked." Not true in my case, I was invoking the controller through the router. Take the original above example:

    `.when('/r/:type/:bar_id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/bar.html',
        controller: 'BarsCtrl',
        resolve: {
            // etc`

The 'BarsCtrl' is being applied to the template located at 'views/bar.html'. If you do not have the controller and template here, that could be your issue...

Comment: This was my problem as well. I wish ng had a controller definition precedent. As i learn more, I find that I migrate from one definition format to another, perhaps on the same view, and this is not the first time the dual-controller definition has bit me.

Answer (score 2):

foo_list <- is the js file for this being loaded in the your html page in a script tag? it just mightbe the case that when you have forgotten to include factory/service/controller and actually have forgotten to include it in a script tag in the index/app html page (or require shims)

Okay just saw your comment and  extending the answer here cos its easier to do it here.

Your code where you declare the controller should read like

```
App.controller('FoosCtrl', 
   ['$scope', '$location', 'Foos', /* comment out foo_list here*/ 
    function($scope, $location, Foos, foo_list /* this remains */) {
  ...
}
```

when the route is getting changed things you mention in 'resolve'  would get resolved by ui-router.  But it the place where you are declaring your FoosCtrl you don't actually have a provider for it to resolve.

Give this a try i had a similar case like this last week.

Comment: `foo_list` is supposed to be promise-resolved and injected by name due to the `resolve` property of the route.

Comment: This will cause the unknown provider error to go away but now foo_list isn't bound to the foo_list in resolve...it's just an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a heads up, I just had a similar issue which was caused by adding the resolve-variables as a dependency to the controller while not having set up the response funciton in the `$stateProvider.state()` yet.

Adding the resolve function fixed the missing dependency
(I still don't quite get why - I'd be glad if anyone could share his knowledge in the comments)

Comment: what is the response function in the state?  Can you clarify with an example?

Comment: Sure. Not the response function but the resolve function. It happens when you require some variable on the controller `.controller('fooCtrl', function(someRequire) { ... });` while not having a resolve on that require defined `.when('...', { resolve: { notDefineSomeRequire: [...] } })`.
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/bfqm7q5d/) for demonstration and compare it to [this fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/2gm7ykxt/) (note the added resolve on `fooState`)

Comment: Strange, I have the resolve function, and it returns a promise.  In my controller, the data comes in alright, but then the unknown error provider for my named parameter is thrown.  IE, in your fiddle, I would get an foo_listProvider error.  It's bizarre.  I can see that the data is sent to the controller when I put a break point in.  The code is executed, and once it leaves the controller the error is thrown by Angular.

Comment: In that case create a new question and feel free to link it here