# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: someProvider <- SomeService

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularjs

I have made sure to register a service like this, inside the services directory inside modules -> module_name

```
angular.module('module_name').factory('service_name', [
    function() {
        // Public API
    console.log('hello');
        return {
            someMethod: function() {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

from this [Error: Unknown provider: employeesProvider <- employees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284793/error-unknown-provider-employeesprovider-employees) i found removing the ngController solves the issue, but
I am trying to render a view that must have a controller to render some model data.

If i remove that ngController, i get no data.

What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have dependency on the employees module (somewhere not shown in your posted code). You need to inject that into this module_name.

```
angular.module('module_name',['employees'])
.factory('service_name', ['employees', function(employees) {
    // Public API
    console.log('hello');
    return {
        someMethod: function() {
            return true;
        }
    };
}]);
```

The dependency could also be in your controller. You should use the similar method to inject the dependency there.

Additional information on [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).