# AngularJS: functions doesn't work when setting route resolve and removing ng-controller directive

Tags: angularjs

I used route resolve to prevent loading view before executing some functions, then I read here [Error: Unknown provider: employeesProvider <- employees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284793/error-unknown-provider-employeesprovider-employees/18305423#18305423) that I have to remove `ng-controller`, then I did

```
<div > <!-- ng-controller="navBar" has removed from here -->
    <div ng-include="'...../partitials/navBar.html'"></div>
</div>
```

here is the route provider

```
$routeProvider
.when("/ERPdocumentation/", {
            templateUrl : function(params){
                // code here
                return template
             },
            controller: "navBar",
            resolve: {
                filteredModules: function (searchForService) {
                   return searchForService.getfilteredModules();
                }
            }
        });
```

But, that made some functions no longer worked in `navBar` controller, for example, when I click this button:

```
<md-button ng-click="routeToSearchPage (searchString)">
```

, the functions doesn't works in the `navBar` controller:

```
angular.module("myApp")
 .controller("navBar", function ($scope,filteredModules, $location) {
    $scope.filteredModules = filteredModules;
    $scope.routeToSearchPage = function(searchString){
        console.log("route") // nothing happened here
        $location.search("search", searchString);
        $location.path($location.$$path);
    };
})
.factory("searchForService", function(){
 return {
        getfilteredModules: function(){
// code here to get search results 
        }
   }
 })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e1vfrcrf/14/
Do i misunderstand something with those concepts?What caused this problem? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution I tried was  not to use the route resolve at all, I's just return the search results from the service directly, this way:

```
        $scope.filteredModules = searchForService.getfilteredModules();
```