# Trying to get my Resolve to inject into my controller to be able to inject into the HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

This is my index.js file

```
'use strict';

angular.module('wildenglish', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'restangular', 'ngRoute',     'ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {

RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/googleCalendarID');

$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    resolve: {
            calendarEvents: function(Restangular){
                return Restangular.one('eventsAUTHKEY').get();
            }
        }
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });


 })
```

And my main controller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('wildenglish')

   .controller('MainCtrl', function(Restangular, calendarEvents) {
      var self = this,
      events = calendarEvents,
      items = events.items;




});
```

The Error I'm receiving when I try to use in the HTML is:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: calendarEventsProvider <- calendarEvents <- MainCtrl

So I am trying to figure out how I can utilize the information that I am getting back from that Promise which I can log in the console to be accessible to the HTML via the controller

Do I need a service or factory? and where would that go?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Are you using `MainCtrl` in ng-controller directive? If so it will not work, you would need to only use it with the route controller binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the events returned by the resolved promise to your controller scope. You'll need to change the depencies your injecting into your controller. You can leave out Restangular since you are resolving your promise in your route but you do need $scope:

```
angular.module('wildenglish').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, calendarEvents) {

    // i'm assuming the following logs your events to your console
    // if not you're having a problem with your Restangular request
    console.log(calendarEvents);

    // Assign calendarEvents to your $scope
    $scope.events = calendarEvents;

});
```

Now you can use the events in your HTML template (assuming each event has a property called 'name'):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="event in events">{{event.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I swear I had tried it that way but must have been missing something. Thank you again for your help and for leading me back in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missed the answer above which is already the correct answer.

There was a similar problem here:

[AngularJS, resolve and unknown provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846466/angularjs-resolve-and-unknown-provider)

Basically if you are using the routeProvider to assign your controller in your script file you cannot use ng-controller in your template.