# UI-Router and resolve, unknown provider in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using resolve in my UI-Router .state() call. In my controller I can access the values no problem, but it is throwing an error as follows:

> $injector/unpr?p0=ctrlOptionsProvider%20%3C-trlOptions

The following code throws the error but allows me to access the variable `ctrlOptions` just fine:

```
.state('new_user', {
            url: "/user/new",
            templateUrl: "views/user/new.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'New User'},
            controller: "UserController",
            resolve: {

                ctrlOptions: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {

                    return {

                        view: 'new_user',
                    }
                }],
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({ 
                        name: 'MetronicApp',  
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.min.js', 
                        ]                    
                    });
                }]
            }
        })
```

---

```
MetronicApp.controller('UserController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', 'ctrlOptions', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $stateParams, ctrlOptions, $timeout) {}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is ctrlOptions ?

Comment: It is something that I have declared in resolve of the UI-Router block. I want to access the values of ctrlOptions in my controller.

Comment: You cannotuse that controller using ng-controller, you must only instantiate it via the route.

Comment: So how can I fix. this looks messy. How can I instantiate view the route?

Comment: You do not have ng-controller="UserController" right? you should be good.

Comment: Ah yes, I did, but removed. Now all is good. Will there be any side affect to this? Is it ok because I am linking the UserController via the route meaning the html view still knows what controller it belongs to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS, resolve and unknown provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846466/angularjs-resolve-and-unknown-provider)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Remove `ng-controller="UserController"` from your view, let the router instantiate the controller.

When you use route resolve argument as dependency injection in the controller bound to the route, you cannot use that controller with ng-controller/or any other directive because the service provider with the name `ctrlOptions` does not exist. It is a dynamic dependency that is injected by the router when it instantiates the controller to be bound in its respective partial view. It is also a better practice not to instantiate a controller with ng-controller and starting a template with ng-controller directive when router can instantiate and bind the controller to that template, template will be more reusable as it is not tightly coupled with the controller name (with ng-controller="ctrlName" ) but only with the contract.

Comment: This just saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: ...I hate it when I do dumb things. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So I had the same problem but my setup is different.
Just posting it in case anyone runs into it too. First time posting an answer so not sure if there's a better place to put an answer that doesn't solve the OP's answer but still solves a variant of the question asked.

#### App State

I have a parent state "app" and a child state "home".
When a User logs in they go through the "app" state which did the resolving and then they get redirected to the "home" state.

```
angular
.module('common')
.component('app', {
    templateUrl: './app.html',
    controller: 'AppController',
    bindings: {
        member: '=',
        organization: '=',
    }
})
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            redirectTo: 'home',
            url: '/app',
            data: {
                requiredAuth: true
            },
            resolve: {
                member: ['AuthService',
                    function (AuthService) {
                        return AuthService.identifyMember()
                            .then(function (res) {
                                AuthService.setAuthentication(true);
                                return res.data;
                            })
                            .catch(function () {
                               return null;
                            });
                    }
                ],
                organization: ['AuthService',
                    function (AuthService) {
                        return AuthService.identifyOrganization()
                            .then(function (res) {
                                return res.data;
                            })
                            .catch(function () {
                                return null;
                            });
                    }
                ],
                authenticated: function ($state, member) {
                    if (!member)
                        $state.go('auth.login');
                }
            },
            component: 'app',
        });
});
```

The solution for me was in the **bindings**. I had done it for member before but forgot to do it for organization so that was my silly problem.

#### Home State

```
angular
.module('components')
.component('home', {
    templateUrl: './home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    bindings: {
        member: '=',
        organization: '=',
    }
})
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        parent: 'app',
        url: '/home',
        data: {
            requiredAuth: true
        },
        component: 'home',
        resolve: {
            'title' : ['$rootScope',
                function ($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.title = "Home";
                }
            ],
        }
    });
});
```

Again the solution was in the **bindings**.

NOTE: I did not have to inject the data into my controller

```
function HomeController(AuthService, $state) {
    let ctrl = this;
}
```

Not sure why I didn't have to inject directly into the controller for it to be available as **ctrl.member** and **ctrl.organization**.

Comment: Typically, the way to do this is post your own question referencing this one, and then answer it yourself. (Assuming these two questions are different enough to warrant separate Q&A.) This builds a library of useful information for future visitors.

Comment: @jdv Thanks for informing me!

Comment: @jdv Should I give a link to the new question as well?

Comment: Typically, people will often have a short preamble to their question that reads something like "This question is similar to this question XYZ but differs in that it asks about the right way to grabnor the fnord, instead of asking why the fnord is used at all."

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and for me problem was that I've assigned controller generally to angular module AND to ui router.
e.g.

I had:

```js
let app: ng.IModule = angular.module('userManagementApp');
app.controller(PartyViewController.IID, PartyViewController); //NOTICE THIS
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
      ($locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider, $routeProvider: any) => {
        $routeProvider.when("something", {
          templateUrl: 'views/partyView/partyView.html',
          controller: PartyViewController.IID, //NOTICE THIS
          controllerAs: 'pvCtrl',
          reloadOnSearch: false,
          resolve: {
            ...
          }
        })
```

But I should have:

```js
let app: ng.IModule = angular.module('userManagementApp');
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
      ($locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider, $routeProvider: any) => {
        $routeProvider.when("something", {
          templateUrl: 'views/partyView/partyView.html',
          controllerAs: 'pvCtrl',
          reloadOnSearch: false,
          resolve: {
            ...
          },
          controller: PartyViewController
        })
```

Problem occured because angular tried to load this controller by its own but it shouldn't - router should.

Answer (score -3):

Is it potentially because of the extra comma here?

```
return {
         view: 'new_user',
        }
```

Try taking the comma out.

Also, you forgot to inject `$timeout` to your controller after `ctrlOptions`

Comment: Comma don't have effect.