# Undefined resolve data in Controller, UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**NOTE:** This question is similar to [UI-Router and resolve, unknown provider in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175785/ui-router-and-resolve-unknown-provider-in-controller/45826016?noredirect=1#comment78685201_45826016) but differs in that it deals specifically with AngularJS 1.5+ and Component-based apps which changes how things are configured for a state resolve.

So I am trying to resolve some data in a child state. I had done this before for a previous resolve but am running into an issue for the 2nd one.

Here is my setup:

#### App State

I have a parent state "app" and a child state "home". When a User logs in they go through the "app" state which did the resolving and then they get redirected to the "home" state.

```
angular
.module('common')
.component('app', {
    templateUrl: './app.html',
    controller: 'AppController',
    bindings: {
        member: '=',
    }
})
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            redirectTo: 'home',
            url: '/app',
            data: {
                requiredAuth: true
            },
            resolve: {
                member: ['AuthService',
                    function (AuthService) {
                        return AuthService.identifyMember()
                            .then(function (res) {
                                AuthService.setAuthentication(true);
                                return res.data;
                            })
                            .catch(function () {
                               return null;
                            });
                    }
                ],
                organization: ['AuthService',
                    function (AuthService) {
                        return AuthService.identifyOrganization()
                            .then(function (res) {
                                return res.data;
                            })
                            .catch(function () {
                                return null;
                            });
                    }
                ],
                authenticated: function ($state, member) {
                    if (!member)
                        $state.go('auth.login');
                }
            },
            component: 'app',
        });
});
```

#### Home State

```
angular
.module('components')
.component('home', {
    templateUrl: './home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    bindings: {
        member: '=',
    }
})
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        parent: 'app',
        url: '/home',
        data: {
            requiredAuth: true
        },
        component: 'home',
        resolve: {
            'title' : ['$rootScope',
                function ($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.title = "Home";
                }
            ],
        }
    });
});
```

And in my controller when I try to console.log the output of what should be there:

```
function HomeController(AuthService, $state) {
    let ctrl = this;
    console.log(ctrl.organization);
}
```

But, I am getting **undefined**.

My methods in AuthService are getting called the same way for the **member** resolve so I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I was simply missing the binding for **organization** in both the App State and Home State:

```
bindings: {
    member: '=',
    organization: '=',
}
```

NOTE: Because I used bindings, I did not have to inject the data into the Controller itself as is shown in the UI-Router docs at the following link:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies

I am not sure why using the bindings allows that but for the purposes of inheriting data from a parent state, it seems to achieve the same result.

EDIT: After rewording my search queries, I was able to find the section in the UI-Router docs that actually shows the same thing that I did:

> Instead of injecting resolve data into the controller, use a one-way component input binding, i.e., <.

https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#create-a-component

This seems to connect the data to the specific Controller like how injecting the data into the Controller connects it as well. Although I am still unsure if any under-the-hood differences between binding and injecting exist.

Given that UI-Router shows the same logic that I had used, this seems to be the proper way to allow a Controller access to resolved data for a particular state.

The only other thing I would say is to pay attention to what type of binding you need to use. You can find the different types and their descriptions here under **Component-based application architecture** and then under **Components have a well-defined public API - Inputs and Outputs**:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component