# Resolve variable for ng-included view

Tags: angularjs, resolve, angularjs-ng-include

This is my app.js:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            resolve: {
                loggedUser: getLoggedUser
            }
}]);
```

The function getLoggedUser() returns a promise which is resolved in `userService` when it has found the logged in user. In my index.html I include a navigation bar:

```
<ng-include src="'partials/navbar.html'" ng-controller="homeController"></ng-include> // Navbar
<div ng-view></div> // Angular views
```

The problems are:

1. ng-controller cannot be used with resolve since it creates an AngularJs error of 'unknown provider'. Therefore, the ng-include creates trouble for the '/' route.
2. I cannot/do not know how to specify a resolve for the navbar since it has no route, but is included in every view in index.html. And the navbar needs to show the name of the logged in user.

EDIT1:
I tried an ugly solution, by returning `myPromise.$$state.value` in `homeController` and removing the `resolve {...}`. However, it feels like I shouldn't use the $q promises like this. Any other suggestions?

EDIT2:
What I mean is that the loggedUser is unknown because of ng-controller="". Here is an explanation: [AngularJS, resolve and unknown provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846466/angularjs-resolve-and-unknown-provider).

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why you get an error about 'unknown provider' is that you need to inject the service `userService` into the resolve function :

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        resolve: {
            loggedUser: function(userService) {
                return userService.getLoggedUser();
            }
        }
}]);
```

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit unclear, I meant that the loggedUser provider is unknown. I updated my answer so you can understand what I mean. This is a result of ng-controller="".

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the navbar from the rest of your app.
Use something like

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller = "navbarController as nav">
    <div ng-show=" userIsLoggedIn"> <!-- show navbar only if true -->
      <!-- navbar markup-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-view> <!-- display other templates here --> </div>
</body>
```

You can then use a `service` in which us store the login status and credentials of the user. As services can be accessed app wide, you can access its data (like the username) in your `navbarController`.

Comment: Well that's what I have right now. The problem is that I want to use the resolve property of the routeProvider, since other controllers use the loggedUser variable and it therefore needs to be a $q promise, but I cannot use ng-controller together with resolve because of what I wrote in EDIT2.