# Angular route resolve [$injector:unpr] error with components

Tags: angularjs

### Important Edit:

For design reasons i changed some things in the structure, so the component has no longer an isolated scope, instead there are a new controller assigned to the view. In any case **the same error persists**, so i'll using this question. Below the code and description.

**old description**

I have a routes file where i get my templates and so on. Two of theese routes uses a full component (a form, btw) with his own controller inside.

They are responsible for resolve some service promises that get info from an API endpoints.

Anyway, when i call them into the controller i get the following error with any resolve function:

**end old description**

The controller is now into a traditional Angular controller, binded to the view in the router, but the error: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: spacesListProvider <- spacesList` persists with spacesLists and all other resolves in the controller.

This is the relevant part of code in the router (the new code):

```
.when('/experiences',{
    templateUrl: 'partials/experiences-list.html',
    controller: 'saas.experienceController',
    controllerAs: 'products',
    resolve: {
        experiencesList: getAllExperiences
    }
})
.when('/experiences/:id',{
    templateUrl: 'partials/single-experience.html',
    controller: 'saas.experienceController',
    controllerAs: 'product',
    resolve: {
        experienceDetail: getExperienceDetail,
        spacesList: getSpaces,
        cancellationsLists: getCancellations
    }
})
.when('/new-experience',{
    templateUrl: 'partials/new-experience.html',
    controller: 'saas.experienceController',
    controllerAs: 'product',
    resolve: {
       experienceDetail: getExperienceDetail,
       spacesList: getSpaces
    }
})
.when('/edit-experience/:id',{
    templateUrl: 'partials/edit-experience.html',
    controller: 'saas.experienceController',
    controllerAs: 'product',
    resolve: {
       experienceDetail: getExperienceDetail,
       spacesList: getSpaces
    }
})
.otherwise({
    templateUrl: '404.html'
});

// Functions
// Experiences

getExperienceDetail.$inject = ['apiService', '$route'];
function getExperienceDetail(apiService, $route) {
    if(!$route.current.params.id){
      return false;
    }
    return apiService.getOneProd($route.current.params.id);
}; // getExperienceDetail

getAllExperiences.$inject = ['apiService'];
function getAllExperiences(apiService) {
    return apiService.getAllProds();
}; // getAllExperiences

getCancellations.$inject = ['apiService', '$route'];
function getCancellations(apiService, $route) {
    if(!$route.current.params.id){
      return false;
    }
    return apiService.getProdCancellations($route.current.params.id);
}; // getCancellations

// Spaces
getSpaces.$inject = ['apiService', '$route'];
function getSpaces(apiService, $route) {
    if(!$route.current.params.id){
      return false;
    }
    return apiService.getProdSlots($route.current.params.id);
}
```

1. ***Note: apiService is a complete service defined in another module***
2. ***Note: all the resolve functions are defined below the router, injected and called via hoisting***

I'm injecting the resolves, the service and all the things into the controller as usual:

```
expCtrl.$inject = ['$routeParams', '$location', 'apiService', 'experiencesList', 'experienceDetail', 'spacesList', 'cancellationsLists'];

function expCtrl($routeParams, $location, apiService, experiencesList, experienceDetail, spacesList, cancellationsLists)...
```

I spend a lot of time searching answers or hints but now I'm stucked. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is spacesList defined? Is it a service or factory or what? In which module is it defined? Is it the same module as the one you're using to define the routes? And if not, is this other module included as a dependency? It is hard to tell where the problem is without more details.

Comment: I'll write an Example in an Answer (even though this may not be your case), to clarify what I mean.

Comment: i'll make some editions in the question because some changes.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvers are local dependencies and available for injection only in route controller and other router resolvers.

`spacesList` should be injected to route controller and propagated to `experienceForm` view element via scope.

If `experienceForm` has isolated scope, resolver can be passed through bound attributes, otherwise it can be taken from route controller's inherited scope.

Answer (score 0):

A probable source for your problem could be, that you're using spacesList without having included it's module as a dependency on the module where you're declaring the experienceForm controller.

```
// Somewhere in a module 'bla' spacesList is declared (as a service??)
angular.module('bla')
    .service('spacesList', spacesList);
spacesList.$inject = [...];
function spacesList(...) { ... };


// include 'bla' module in 'module1' to be able to inject spacesList
angular.module('module1', ['bla'])
    .controller('experienceForm', experienceForm);

experienceForm.$inject = ['$routeParams', '$location', 'apiService', 'spacesList', 'experienceDetail'];
function experienceForm($routeParams, $location, apiService, spacesList, experienceDetail)...
```

**Update based on the new updates/comments**

Ok, then I think the problem is probably caused while `spacesList` is being figured out and the error is a bit missleading, i.e. while angular is defining spacesList, it goes to `getSpaces` an there an error occurs and so `spacesList` doesn't gets defined and the error thrown is just about spacesList not being defined at all but not telling us where the problem really is. So my theory is, getSpaces is the one with the problem.

What about trying something like this:

You mentioned, that getSpaces uses 'apiService' and the resolvers are some functions declared underneath... Have you tried declaring the resolvers as inline functions and injecting them a service which in turn gets the `apiService` injected?

Supposing module is available on a variable `module1`.

And make sure to check that the module from `apiService` is included on the dependencies of the module where the routes are being declared (e.g. the part including the 'bla' of my example above in 'module1')...

```
module1.service('getSpacesSvc', getSpacesSvc);

getSpacesSvc.$inject = ['apiService', ...];
function getSpacesSvc(apiService, ...) {
    this.getStuff = function() {
        return apiService.getSomething();
    }
}

// And then on your routes
resolve: {
    spacesList: function(getSpacesSvc) {
        return getSpacesSvc.getStuff();
    }
}
```

Also if that doesn't work or you already tried that, try first using an extremely basic function (as a service like the example above), with no other dependencies, returning some hard-coded fixtures for example. And if that works, then you'll have at least a starting point to build on top of.

**Update #2**

I also just found some similar issues, which might be the cause of your problem. Are you by change using the `ng-controller` directive on any of the templates used on the routes?

E.g. check that no `ng-controller="saas.experienceController"` is used on the template.

For more details look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18305438/466275

Comment: Answering to some of your questions: **No**, `spacesList` insnt declared as a service because it isn't a service, is the name of the resolve that invoke `getSpaces`. Here: `resolve: { ... , spacesList: getSpaces }` and then injected into the controller. In fact, `getSpaces` have a service (`apiService`) injected which calls some factories promises.