# UI-Router Resolve Undefined when injected into Controller even though I am returning a promise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router, promise

I am using ngResource with ui-router resolve. When I inject the resolved data (postsResolved) into the controller the controller is not recognizing 'postsResolved'

I do not understand why since I believe the function for postsResolved is returning a promise

Config

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/post");

    $stateProvider
        .state('post', {
            url: "/post",
            templateUrl: "post/_post.html",
            resolve: {
                postsResolve: function(Post){
                    return Post.index().$promise;
                }
            },
            controller: 'postCtrl'
        });
}]);
```

Controller

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('postCtrl', ['$scope', 'Post','$stateParams', 'postsResolve', function($scope, Post, $stateParams, postsResolve) {

        $scope.posts = postsResolve;

}]);
```

Factory/Resource

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router','templates', 'ngResource'])
    .factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource){
        return $resource("/posts/:id", {id: "@id"},
            {
                'create': {method: 'POST'},
                'index': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
                'show': {method: 'GET', isArray: false},
                'update': {method: 'PUT'},
                'destory': {method: 'DELETE'}
            }
        );

    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846466/angularjs-resolve-and-unknown-provider)

Found the answer to my question, had to remove the ng-controller from my template for resolve to work since we are declaring the controller in the ui-router config portion.